# Android: clear a listArray stored in sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I currently am storing a `listArray` in `sharedPreferences`, and then I am displaying this `listArray` in a `ListView` as shown below

```
public class Savelistarray extends ListActivity {

    private static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "MY_SHARED_PREF";

    public static ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public void advancenext (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SaveScores.this, Splash.class);
        SaveScores.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_scores);

        setupActionBar();

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        mylist = (ArrayList<String>) getArray();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);

        mylist.add(String.valueOf(PreviousActivity.value));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);        

    }

    public boolean saveArray() {

        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sp.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(mylist);        
        mEdit1.putStringSet("list", set);

        return mEdit1.commit();     

    }

    public List<String> getArray() {
        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set = sp.getStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>());
        return new ArrayList<String>(set);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        saveArray();
        super.onStop();
        SaveScreen.datevalue = null;
    }

}
```

Now, **my goal is to give the user the option to reset this `listArray` and `ListView` from a different activity** by clicking the button `reset`. This is what I have done so far

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        final Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);

        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Savelistarray.mylist.clear();

                //New Code
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1.remove("mylist");
                SharedPreferences sp.getStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>());
            }

        });

    }

}
```

However, this does not clear the `listArray` or the `ListView`. Does anyone know how to approach this?

**EDIT** In the update `//New Code`, I get the errors `The method remove(String) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}` and `The method getStringSet(String, HashSet<String>) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`.

Comment: PreferenceEditor.remove("key"); Then when you get the pref set the default to a new empty list.

Comment: @zgc7009 what would the `key` be in this instance? Also, would I need to set the preference default do an empty list, or some other default?

Comment: mEdit1.remove("list"); ... sp.getStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>());

Comment: @zgc7009 I updated my answer but I still get some errors

Answer (score 0):

you can try this - in the Next activity set a variable to 1 using sharedpreference. override onResume() function in savelistarray activity and get the variable from sharedpreferences, now clear the list and store 0 in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this which is why I wanted to leave it as a comment for now, but you seem to be having some trouble so I figured I would at least give you a start.

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1;
    private Set<String> set;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);

        sp = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME,  Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEdit1 = sp.edit();
        set = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        mEdit1.remove("mylist").commit();

        // add this if you want to check and make sure that you
        // have removed your key value, if it has worked, set will
        // be set to a new, empty Set String, if not, it set will
        // be the old key value
        set = sp.getStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>());
    }

}
```

In the onClick method, you could also try

```
mEdit1.putStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>()).commit();
```

Instead of

```
mEdit1.remove("list").commit();
```

I guess it is really up to you if both work.

Test it, see if it works. If it does, I will give a more detailed answer as to what is really going on. If not, let me know what isn't working and I should be able to help.